# How to execute another PHP file?

Tags: php, mysql, json, execute

My question is: is there a way to execute another php file after HTML form post? I don't want to use header, because i don't want to go to the php page, i only want to execute it.

Clarification:

My i have an addmatch.php, which shows a form where you can add fiels to a table with matches + it shows the table with matches. This PHP page executes the insert.php, which adds data to the SQL database. After adding a field/match, i want to return (i use a header in the insert.php) to the addmatch.php with the updated tabel. So far so good, it works.

But now i my problem: after adding a field, i want to execute another php file. This file, named json.php, is responsible for echoeing json objects of the SQL data. This works. But now my problem is: it only works when i refresh this page after adding a field to the table. But i want to refresh it automatically after adding a field/match on the addmatch.php file WITHOUT open this php file. Is this possible? And how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking about **possibilities** and **is not a concrete coding question**. If you want to know if something is possible you should **research it** and **attempt to implement it**. If you have issues while doing this you then can ask a **specific** question, **showing the code you have written**, your expected results, and your actual results.

Comment: Try call it via `curl`

Comment: This sounds as a work for ajax, specially if you are working with JSON which abbreviates for: JavaScript Object Notation

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question .... you may use jquery & ajax . on submit run the ajax code without need to refresh the page .